# Use SQL to implement an API to pull public data based on a column from table (companies house UK)

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, t-sql

I have spent some time searching some questions on here for a solution.  I have absolutely no experience of using API's and my developer days are way behind me.  Companies House in the UK has an API and I have my API key.

I have a dataset which contains a company registration number.  I want to loop through those records and then for each company number, get the filing deadlines in a table updated.  I then will present this data in Power BI.

I'm ok handling the records and I'm ok presenting the data.

What I have absolutely no idea to do is implement this within a SQL query.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'https://api.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

I seen this example above but I need to construct a valid GET within my cursor and also pass my API key.

https://developer-specs.company-information.service.gov.uk/guides/introduction

I have absolutely no idea what I am doing.  I have enabled Ole Automation Procedures and I know there are probably better more secure ways to do it.  I am looking for someone to be able to help me get it running and I can do the rest.

Could someone please help me out with this one?

Thank you

Comment: Honestly, don't try to call APIs from T-SQL; those old OA objects are *old* and not maintained. Use middleware to call the APIs. If you "must" do the calls from T-SQL, then create CLR objects to do this work.

Comment: If you have Power BI at your disposal you'd frankly be nuts not to take advantage of its extensive support for importing data from web resources and pouring it into any shape you like. Even if you also need to update local SQL data (and there is no way around that, for example by combining the local data with the retrieved data) I'm not sure I wouldn't just import the data into an SSAS instance with PBI and then query that. Other alternatives include Power Automate, SSIS (if you absolutely must) or custom client code. Heck, even Python code started from SQL Server (it supports that now).